# PAC1921 power monitor issue

Tags: stm32, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, power-measurement

I'm trying to measure voltage, current and power by PAC1921 IC.

This is a PAC1921 datasheet:

[PAC1921 DataSheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PAC1921-Data-Sheet-DS20005293E.pdf)

This is my schematic:

[image]

3.3V_Input is input from simple AMS1117 3.3 V regulator and +3.3 V goes to the STM32 MCU.

This is my source code:

```
   #include <string.h>

   #include "PAC1921.h"

   #include "errorcodes.h"

   //=================================================================================================
   pac1921_config pac_cfg_;
   static u8 reg_control_;
   static u8 reg_icfg_;

   static u8 read(i2c_config* i2c_cfg, u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8* data, u16 size);

   static u8 meas_type_ = 0xFF;

   //=================================================================================================
   u8 PAC1921_Init(pac1921_config* pac_cfg)
{
u8 err = ERROR_NO;
u8 product_id;
u8 revision_id;
u8 manufacturer_id;

memcpy(&pac_cfg_, pac_cfg, sizeof(pac1921_config));

err = read(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_PRODUCT_ID, &product_id, 1);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

err = read(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_MANUFACTURER_ID, &manufacturer_id, 1);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

err = read(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_REVISION_ID, &revision_id, 1);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//PAC1921_SetReadState();

//
// Set Gain Configuration Register
//

u8 reg_gain = (pac_cfg_.Vsense_ADC_res << 0x07) |
              (pac_cfg_.Vbus_ADC_res << 0x06)   |
              (pac_cfg_.DI_GAIN << 0x03)        |
              (pac_cfg_.DV_GAIN);

err = I2C_Write_CLR(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_GAIN_CONFIG,
                    I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_gain, 1, 1000);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Set Integration Configuration Register
//

reg_icfg_ = (pac_cfg_.num_sumples << 0x04) |
            (READ_INT_OVERRIDE << 0x01)    |
            (FORCE_INTEGRATE_MODE);

err = I2C_Write_CLR(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_INTEGRATION_CONFIG,
                    I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_icfg_, 1, 1000);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//
// Set Control Register
//

reg_control_ = (pac_cfg_.out_fsr_voltage << 0x04) |
               (FORCE_READ_MODE << 0x01)          |
               (FORCE_RECALCUALTE_MODE);

err = I2C_Write_CLR(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_CONTROL,
                    I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_control_, 1, 1000);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

//PAC1921_SetIntegrationState();

return err;
   }

   //=================================================================================================
   u8 PAC1921_GetData(u8 meas_type, f32* val)
   {
u8 err = ERROR_NO;
u8 reg_dst = 0x00;
u16 out_fsr = 0x00;
u16 res = 0x00;
u8 i_max = 10;
u8 v_max = 32;
u8 buffer[2];

//PAC1921_SetReadState();

reg_control_ &= 0x3F;
reg_control_ |= (meas_type << 0x06);

if(meas_type_ != meas_type)
{
    err = I2C_Write_CLR(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_CONTROL,
                        I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_control_, 1, 1000);
    if(err != ERROR_NO)
    {
        return err;
    }

    meas_type_ = meas_type;
}

if(meas_type_ != meas_type)
{
    err = I2C_Write_CLR(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, REG_CONTROL,
                        I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &reg_control_, 1, 1000);
    if(err != ERROR_NO)
    {
        return err;
    }

    meas_type_ = meas_type;
}


if(meas_type == OUTPUT_TYPE_VSENSE_FREE_RUN)
{
    reg_dst = REG_VSENSE_RESULT_HBYTE;
    out_fsr = 100;
}
else if(meas_type == OUTPUT_TYPE_VBUS_FREE_RUN)
{
    reg_dst = REG_VBUS_RESULT_HBYTE;
    out_fsr = 32000;
}
else if(meas_type == OUTPUT_TYPE_VPOWER_FREE_RUN)
{
    reg_dst = REG_VPOWER_RESULT_HBYTE;
}

//PAC1921_SetIntegrationState();

err = read(&pac_cfg_.i2c_cfg, pac_cfg_.dev_addr | 0x01, reg_dst, buffer, 2);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

res = buffer[0];
res <<= 0x02;
res |= (buffer[1] >> 6);

*val = res / 1023.0f;

if(meas_type == OUTPUT_TYPE_VPOWER_FREE_RUN)
{
    *val *= i_max;
    *val *= v_max;
}
else
{
    *val *= out_fsr;
}

return err;
}

   u8 PAC1921_GetMeasurements(f32* V_bus, f32* V_sense, f32* power)
{
u8 err = ERROR_NO;

/*err = PAC1921_GetData(OUTPUT_TYPE_VSENSE_FREE_RUN, V_sense);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}*/

err = PAC1921_GetData(OUTPUT_TYPE_VBUS_FREE_RUN, V_bus);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

err = PAC1921_GetData(OUTPUT_TYPE_VPOWER_FREE_RUN, power);

return err;
}

void PAC1921_SetIntegrationState(void)
{
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(pac_cfg_.read_int_port, pac_cfg_.read_int_pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void PAC1921_SetReadState(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(pac_cfg_.read_int_port, pac_cfg_.read_int_pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

static u8 read(i2c_config* i2c_cfg, u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8* data, u16 size)
{
u8 err = ERROR_NO;

err = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(i2c_cfg->handle, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, &reg_addr, 1, 1000);
if(err != ERROR_NO)
{
    return err;
}

err = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(i2c_cfg->handle, pac_cfg_.dev_addr, data, size, 1000);

return err;
}
```

When I'm trying to get Vpower, I always get zero and I can't understand how to get current flowing through resistor, i.e how much current STM32 MCU consumes.

BTW this is my configuration setting.

I set for GAIN CONFIGURATION REGISTER (ADDRESS 00H)

1. bit 7 _RES , Vsense ADC resolution 11 bit.
2. bit 6 V_RES, Vbus ADC resolution 11 bit.
3. bit 5-3 DI_GAIN 1X
4. bit 2-0 DV_GAIN 1X

for INTEGRATION CONFIGURATION REGISTER (ADDRESS 01H) I set.

1. bit 7-4, SMPL 512
2. bit 1 RIOV
3. bit 0 INTEN

for CONTROL REGISTER (ADDRESS 02H) I set

1. bit 7-6, MXSL = Vpower free-run (I'm changing it in runtime)
2. bit 5-4, OFSR 3V FSR
3. bit 1, SLPOV = Forced Read mode
4. bit 0, RDAC = 1 (Forced recalculate)

Comment: You have pullups on the I2C lines, the RESERVED connected to 3V3 use the correct 1001_101(r/w) address and follow the block read protocoll outlined in table 5.8?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I do not use SMSbus , so RESERVED pin is not connected to anything(floating). Yes I did follow block read protocol in table 5.8

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm trying to get Vpower, I always get zero and I can't understand how to get current flowing through resistor, i.e how much current STM32 MCU consumes.

First of all, you should also explain the settings you have selected and sent to the measurement IC.

---

For a full scale of 100 mV (i.e. unity `DI_GAIN`) and 11-bit resolution, the LSB becomes 49 uV or ~5 mA. So, any current below that will be read as zero by the IC. For 14-bit resolution, the LSB becomes 6 uV or 0.6 mA. In any case, if your MCU consumes less than half a milliamp, this will be read as zero.

Note that `DI_GAIN` changes the full scale. It's unclear what settings you have sent to the IC but you may want to play with the settings or change the sense resistor to something higher e.g. 1 Ohm.

---

**EDIT:** OP's edit about the configuration confirms that the problem comes from the sense resistor. The full-scale sense voltage is 100 mV and the resolution is 11 bits, making the LSB (1-bit voltage) about 49 uV. Therefore the minimum sense current is ~5 mA. Anything below 5 mA will be read as zero by the IC, hence zero consumption.

The solution is to increase the sense resistor or play with `DI_GAIN` to adjust the full-scale voltage. The latter might be problematic due to the IC's input offset error. Increasing the sense resistor appears to be the most practical solution.

Comment: how did you get 49uV and 5mA for 11 bit resolution or 6uV and 0.6mA for 14 bit resolution?

Comment: @Alatriste Divide 100mV (full scale sense voltage for unity gain) by 2^(res). Substitute res with 11 or 14. This will give you LSB (1 bit voltage) in mV (or uV). Divide the result by 0.01 (Ohms) and this will give you minimum sense current.

Comment: please look at my question, I wrote my whole configuration

Comment: Where did you find "Divide 100mV (full scale sense voltage for unity gain) by 2^(res)." this equation?

Comment: @Alatriste it's basic ADC. Don't you know how it works? The full-scale voltage is 100 mV, and the resolution is 11 bits (2^11 = 2048 steps), so each bit corresponds to 100 mV / 2048 = 49 uV. To drop 49 uV across 0.01R resistor you need 4.9 mA. Anything below 4.9 mA will drop less than 49 uV, so your IC will read this as zero. Also, read the datasheet for config and other details.

Comment: BTW I measured with multimeter and my MCU consumes ~34 milliamp.

Comment: @Alatriste seems a bit high to me. What modules (timers, ADCs, GPIOs) are you using in your MCU? What external things does it drive? ~30 mA drops 300 uV across the 10 mR sense resistor. Do you measure ~300 mV across R16?

Comment: It's just STM32F103C8 blue pill. I'm using ONLY one I2C to communicate with PAC1921, one USART to see results and one GPIO input pin for PAC1921's out pin. nothing else.

Comment: @Alatriste alright, that might consume ~30 mA. Now verify if the voltage drop across R16 is ~0.3 mV. There might be something wrong with your layout/setup.

Comment: I see ~ -0.1-0.2 mv drop, my voltmeter is not good enough..sometimes -0.3mV

Comment: @Alatriste You need to verify the drop across R16. Then you should expect and output. What you can try is to replace R16 with 1 Ohm (or maybe higher). That way you'll be able to measure relatively higher voltages. Expect ~30 mV drop.

Comment: ok I will change the resistor

Comment: I do have -0.3mV voltage drop across R16 and MCU consumes 33.8 mA,

Comment: @Alatriste in any case it's better to increase the R16 (e.g. 1 Ohm sounds good).